# Insert items to lists within a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to create a list of multiple lists, considering one list in particular.

For example: I want to add items from `a`, `b`, `c` into `x` list, and then append `x` to one main list.

```
mainlist = []
x = [1, 2, 3] # items will be added hear.

a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
b = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
c = ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']
```

First I need to create a list of lists for `x`:

```
x = [[i] for i in x]
```

It returns:

```
out[1]: [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Now, I want to add items to those lists:

```
for item in range(0, len(x)):
    x[item].insert(1, a[item])

out[2]: [[1, 'a1'], [2, 'b1'], [3, 'c1']]
```

And then append to `mainlist`:

```
mainlist.append(x)
out[3]: [[[1, 'a1'], [2, 'b1'], [3, 'c1']]]
```

My question is how can I add items from `b` and `c` as I did with `a` list, in order to get this output:

```
[[[1, 'a1'], [2, 'b1'], [3, 'c1']], [1, 'a2'], [2, 'b2'], [3, 'c2']], [1, 'a3'], [2, 'b3'], [3, 'c3']]]
```

I tried this, and I got the result, however i think this code could be improved.

```
item1 = [[i] for i in x]
item2 = [[i] for i in x]
item3 = [[i] for i in x]

for i in range(0, len(item1)):
    item1[i].insert(1, a[i])

for i in range(0, len(item2)):
    item2[i].insert(1, b[i])

for i in range(0, len(item3)):
    item3[i].insert(1, c[i])

mainlist.append(item1)
mainlist.append(item2)
mainlist.append(item3)
```

Any suggestions to improve it are appreacited. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just *zip* *x* with each of the lists *a,b,c* using a *list comp*:

```
x = [1, 2, 3] # items will be added hear.

a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
b = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
c = ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']

main_list = [zip(x, y) for y in a,b,c]
```

That will give you:

```
[[(1, 'a1'), (2, 'b1'), (3, 'c1')], [(1, 'a2'), (2, 'b2'), (3, 'c2')], [(1, 'a3'), (2, 'b3'), (3, 'c3')]]
```

If you really want sublists instead of tuples you can call *map* to map the tuples to lists:

```
 [list(map(list, zip(x, y))) for y in a,b,c]
```

If you were going to use a regular loop without the *zip* logic, you would do something like:

```
l = []
for y in a, b, c: 
    l.append([[x[i], ele] for i, ele in enumerate(y)])
print(l)
```

Or a list comp version of the same:

```
 [[[x[i], ele] for i, ele in enumerate(y) ] for y in a, b, c]
```

Presuming all are the same length as `x`, each `i` is the index of the current element in `y` and we match it up with the corresponding element from `x` which is also exactly what zip is doing.

Comment: Thanks, @Padraic. Great solution. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No worries, the difference with zip is it would truncate to the length of the shortest list, enumerate would give an IndecError.